# PHP compile fails with undefined symbols for architecture x86_64, libiconv on macOS Sierra

Tags: php, macos, iconv, macos-sierra, libiconv

I have upgraded a Mac to macOS 10.12.0 Sierra, and am trying to upgrade PHP to version 7.0.9, but 'make test' fails with:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_libiconv", referenced from:
      _zif_iconv_substr in iconv.o
      _zif_iconv_mime_encode in iconv.o
      _php_iconv_string in iconv.o
      __php_iconv_strlen in iconv.o
      __php_iconv_strpos in iconv.o
      __php_iconv_appendl in iconv.o
      _php_iconv_stream_filter_append_bucket in iconv.o
      ...
  "_libiconv_close", referenced from:
      _zif_iconv_substr in iconv.o
      _zif_iconv_mime_encode in iconv.o
      _php_iconv_string in iconv.o
      __php_iconv_strlen in iconv.o
      __php_iconv_strpos in iconv.o
      __php_iconv_mime_decode in iconv.o
      _php_iconv_stream_filter_factory_create in iconv.o
      ...
  "_libiconv_open", referenced from:
      _zif_iconv_substr in iconv.o
      _zif_iconv_mime_encode in iconv.o
      _php_iconv_string in iconv.o
      __php_iconv_strlen in iconv.o
      __php_iconv_strpos in iconv.o
      __php_iconv_mime_decode in iconv.o
      _php_iconv_stream_filter_factory_create in iconv.o
      ...
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [libs/libphp7.bundle] Error 1
```

I compiled it with:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/php5 --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --sysconfdir=/etc --with-config-file-path=/etc --with-zlib --with-zlib-dir=/usr --with-openssl=/usr/local --enable-exif --enable-ftp --enable-mbstring --enable-mbregex --enable-sockets --with-pdo-mysql=mysqlnd --with-mysqli=mysqlnd --with-apxs2=/usr/local/apache2/bin/apxs --enable-zip --with-curl
```

and have tried adding different '--with-iconv-dir=' options but always get the same undefined symbols error.

I have downloaded and compiled libiconv to no avail. Even configured the compile with:

CFLAGS='-arch x86_64' CCFLAGS='-arch x86_64' CXXFLAGS='-arch x86_64' ./configure

but that made no difference. Any suggestions?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: As a compilation problem, did you also make sure to ask on the appropriate PHP mailing list? (http://php.net/mailing-lists.php, probably the "Installation issues and problems" list)

Comment: Thanks Mike. Will do.

Answer (score 9):

This might solve the problem

```
vim Makefile
find EXTRA_LDFALGS and EXTRA_LDFLAGS_PROGRAMS
remove L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/usr/lib
```

Comment: Can you clarify what "this" is and how to use it?

Comment: Is there a way to make a fix in the `./configure` command? How can we exclude the MacOSX library without manually editing the `Makefile`?

Comment: Yes, this did it for me, too. I didn't eliminate that line but simply moved it after "-L / usr/local/iconv/lib" (which is my compiled-from-source iconv lib) in each line where I found a reference to the Xcode path (note that there are also -rpath references to -L.... and change those to be at the end of the line as well

Comment: Actually, I ran into this same thing in a different way compiling git and it caused me to go deep and figure out what was really going on and solve it. I created [a post to explain why this is happening with iconv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57734434/libiconv-or-iconv-undefined-symbol-on-mac-osx/57734435).

Answer (score 4):

1. brew install libiconv  `(libiconv will install in /usr/local/opt/libiconv/)`
2. find **EXTRA_LIBS** variable  in MakeFile.
3. change  `-liconv` to `/usr/local/opt/libiconv/lib/libiconv.dylib`

Here is the reason:

- Mac os has its own `libiconv.dylib`  in `dir/usr/lib/libiconv.dylib`, which do not 
  contains `_libiconv  _libiconv_close . founctions`. Update to a **new libiconv version** and  reference to it will solve the case

Answer (score -1):

I'll teach you. That's caused due to broken symbol during your php source code compilation process.

Since OS X uses llvm toolchain based clang, and the php original source code is based on GNU libraries in which it's compatible for gcc only rather than clang you're already familiar with.

**

> Their architectures seem to be incompatible somehow.

**

In one word, original libiconv source code was definitely not compatible with OS X.
Installing by the command in OS X resolved the issues:

> brew install libiconv.

taehwanjeoung@taehwanui-MacBookAir ~ % brew install libiconv

Updating Homebrew...
==> Auto-updated Homebrew!
Updated 1 tap (homebrew/core).
==> New Formulae
ghz
==> Updated Formulae
ammonite-repl       contentful-cli      gwt                 libwebsockets       salt
angular-cli         detekt              homeassistant-cli   mapserver           stress-ng
ask-cli             ethereum            katago              php                 topgrade
bazel               exploitdb           lerna               php@7.2
borgmatic           fastlane            libdeflate          php@7.3
conan               gatsby-cli          libmypaint          pidgin

Warning: **libiconv 1.16** is already installed and up-to-date
To reinstall 1.16, run `brew reinstall libiconv`

Because it'll be installing OS X-compatible library with complete x86-64bit symbol.

I had same issue yesterday when I was about to practicing php 5 earlier version. I compiled successfully on OS X - the latest version "Mac OS X 10.15.4, Catalina."

**I'm advising you that you do not use the latest version of every development toolchain as always. In a way, you would be conflicting less, it directly means less time consuming when you're doing more important tasks.**

and you even need to edit Makefile before you command "make" to compile on OS X.

Mac developer often uses "nano command line tool instead of vi":

> nano Makefile

and then find EXTRA_LIBS environment variable change -liconv to /usr/local/opt/libiconv/lib/libiconv.dylib - where it is location for Mac OS X compatible library is installed by homebrew.
Because -liconv's default path is somewhere else: /usr/lib/ - which the incompatible with broken architecture symbol resides.

So where can you see the diffs between linux kernel system and OS X system:
.so file exension for linux one and dylib for mac os one?

> The names imply their compiling architecture and the structure inside
>   are a little bit different.

I added more reasonable details for you beside the answer snippet above to explain clearly.

So let me explaining at one point:

> It is the issue of broken architecture symbols during your GNU source
>   code compilation which is not compatible to OS X Unix system
>   environment.
>   Because OS X is more BSD system alike than is linux kernel alike.

- I'm developing hobbyist. so I don't even know all. you'll need to learn everyday also. good luck.

> I would like to recommend you read the book "The Software
>   Craftsman - written by Sandro Mancuso." It is more suitable method(not a tool anyway) for
>   developing and debugging spaces I personally can think of. Someone else denies that
>   somehow.

Comment: I'm trying help myself and moreover I headed even to stack overflow to help others sometimes.